# KendoUI - Read edited data from grid cells using underlying model

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

below i have a kendoUI grid that fetches data from a server.  The user can then edit two columns in the grid.  I have a separate button that will post the data back to the server and i do not use the kendo grid's UPDATE transport for this.  The problem i am having is that if i fetch the data from the grid, it does not reflect the user inputs.  For example, to get to the underlying data for the grid i do the following:

```
products= $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()
```

But when i iterate over products and check the NewPrice or Comment property, it's always blank.   Here is how the grid's data source is defined:

```
dataSource: {
  transport: {
    read: function (options) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/Portal/API/GetProductPrices?id=" + pId,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          localModel.userId = data.userId;
          localModel.products = data.Products;
          return options.success(model.products);
        },
      });
    }
  },
},
scrollable: false,
selectable: true,
schema: {
  model: {
    id: 'Id',
    fields: {
      Item: { type: 'string', editable: false },
      Price: { type: 'number', editable: false },
      NewPrice: { type: 'number', editable: true },
      Comment: { type: 'string', editable: true, validation: { required: true } },
    }
  }
},
columns: [
  { field: "Price", title:"Price"},
  {
    field: "NewPrice", title: "<span class='editMode'>Proposed Value</span>", format: "{0:p}", attributes: { style: "text-align:center;" }, headerAttributes: { style: "text-align:center;" }, width: "50px",
    template: "#=NewValueTemplate(data)#",
  },
  { field: "Comment", title: "<span class='editMode viewWorkflowMode'>Notes</span>", width: "210px", template: "#=NotesTemplate(data)#" },
]
```

Any advice in resolving would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, i needed to allow some rows based on data rules to enter 'edit mode' at the same time, so specifying inline, popup, etc was not an option. What i did instead was use a custom template function when defining the grid columns.  the custom template function returned html, but in the html i used the data-bind attribute to bind to my model.  Finally on the DataBound event of the grid, i bind my model to the rows.

```
field: "NewPrice", title: "New", format: "{0:p}", template: "#=newValueTemplate(d)#",

....
....
function newValueTemplate(d){
     if (d.IsEditable)
         return "<input type='number' data-bind='value:NewPrice' />"
     else 
         return "<span />"
}

function gridDataBound(e){
    var items = this.dataSource.view();
    var gridRows = this.tbody.children();
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                kendo.bind(gridRows[i], items[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the editing type that you are using.
Which type are you using: **inline, batch or popup** ?

Is only this the datasource ? I see no update function.
I suggest you take a look at the three demos.
[Batch](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing)
[Inline](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline)
[Popup](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup)

The worst thing is that you haven't specified the value of the property **editable**.
By default it is **false**, that means the kendoGrid is not editable, 
even if you have specified `editable: true` over your model fields.

[Shortcut to "Editable" configuration](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-editable)

**update #2** : 
As already said [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-data)

> If the data source is bound to a remote service (via the transport option) the data method will return the service response.

So, when you use `dataSource.data()` method on your grid, if you haven't updated correctly your datasource, you should receive all "old" data. (I found strange that you get blank value over those properties, maybe a cache problem)

As I already said, your dataSource doens't provide no update function.

[Here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.update) you are an example about the configuration of the update function in kendo dataSource, with request to remote service.

Suggest you to look on both examples:

*Example - specify update as a string* **and** *Example - specify update as a function*

Comment: i am not using any inline or popup editing.  I am using a single edit, save, cancel button.  the edit button changes the templates of all items to input controls all at once.  when the user is done, the click save.  i was able to resolve this using the 'data-bind' attribute and when the grid datasource is bound, iterate over my model and bind teach to a row of the grid.  thanks much for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please implement the logic from the following example:

```js
var _roleDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { id: 1, title: "Software Engineer" },
        { id: 2, title: "Quality Assurance Engineer" },
        { id: 3, title: "Team Lead" },
        { id: 4, title: "Manager" }
    ]
});

var _peopleDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { id: 1, name: "John", roleId: 1, roleTitle: "Software Engineer" },
        { id: 2, name: "Dave", roleId: 2, roleTitle: "Quality Assurance Engineer" },
        { id: 3, name: "Aaron", roleId: 3, roleTitle: "Team Lead" },
                { id: 4, name: "Russell", roleId: 4, roleTitle: "Manager" }
    ]
});

var _grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: _peopleDataSource,
    columns: [
        {
            field: "name",
            title: "Name"
        },{
            field: "roleTitle",
            title: "Role",
            editor: function(container, options) {
                $("<input data-bind='value:roleTitle' />")
                    .attr("id", "ddl_roleTitle")
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        dataSource: _roleDataSource,
                        dataTextField: "title",
                        dataValueField: "title",
                        template: "<span data-id='${data.id}'>${data.title}</span>",
                        select: function(e) {
                            var id = e.item.find("span").attr("data-id");
                            var person =_grid.dataItem($(e.sender.element).closest("tr"));
                            person.roleId = id;
                            
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $("#log")
                                    .prepend($("<div/>")
                                        .text(
                                            JSON.stringify(_grid.dataSource.data().toJSON())
                                         ).append("<br/><br/>")
                                    );
                                });
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    ],
    editable: true
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
<br/>
<div id="log"></div>
```

You may view the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/khNsE/175/